# how to create Instances in WEKA if Instance values are sets?

Tags: xml, csv, set, weka, instances

**if suppose we have,**

```
x=2, y=3,z=5, class="first"
x=3, y=5,z=10, class="second"
```

we can use csvloader or using arrf we can create **Instances** for any classifer with Weka.

**but what if suppose we have,**

```
x={2,3,4,5}, y={10,11,12,13}, z={6,3,9,5} class="biogancy"
x={7,6,2,3},y={3,2,8,4}, z={4,3,9,7} class="uiopnt"
```

how can i create Instance object for each row? Is there any simple approach like csvloader? How can i manage above rows in csv file? Do i need to use xml? If so, how can i build Instances from above rows in WEKA?

Answer (score 0):

The relational attribute is the thing which comes nearest to your description. It allows you to use multiple instances, but you can only use one bag: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Multi-instance+classification

You can use the ARFF format to specify the data. If you have to use a csv file you might have to implement the loader yourself.

However, if it possible to decompose the sets into a reasonable number of attributes with boolean values, I would do so. As described in the wiki, there is only one package weka.classifiers.mi that offers multi-instance classifiers.

It seems that you would have to use more than one bag anyway. In this case you might want to look for another alternative.

Comment: Have you already looked at [link](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file)? This site provides an example with the relational attribute described above.

Comment: i am completely lost because of two issues in my post. The provided link is not so constructive for me to understand myself. Second, three sets i mentioned above doesn't need to be in fixed size. Let me put in this way, values can be like this,
x={2,3,4,5}, y={10,11,12,13}, z={6,3,9,5} class="biogancy"
x={7,6,2,3,10,13},y={3,2,8,4,2,7}, z={4,3,9,7,9,6} class="uiopnt"
and also i want to know how Instances object is created. because the example provided in above link is showing few errors like:
atts.addElement(new Attribute("att5", dataRel, 0));
vals[4] = data.attribute(4).addRelation(dataRel);

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest another alternative?

If the values in each are discrete and bounded, you can create binary attributes to model each set. For example, let's assume that x, y, z are all subsets of {1,2,3}; in this case, your instances will contain 9(+1) attributes:

```
x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2, z3, class
```

This representation may be too sparse for your needs, but it still is a complete mathematical description of your instances. To tackle the sparseness issue, I suggest using WEKA's awesome feature selection tools. If that's not good enough, you can always resort to more sophisticated dimension reduction methods.